# Laravel 9 Vue 3 Inertia Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I'm building an SPA with Laravel and Vue.js with vite, and I have another project with Laravel Breeze and Inertia js for the CMS. How can I merge these 2 projects into one ? So I can have an SPA project with CMS on it like an admin page that u can set through the routes.
Is it possible ?

This is the app.js in my CMS project

```
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

This is the app.js in my SPA project

```
import '../css/navbar.css';
import '../css/home.css';
import '../css/kenapa.css';
import '../css/ceritakami.css';
import '../css/karir.css';
import '../css/lowongan.css';
import '../css/media.css';
import '../css/gabung.css';
import '../css/mitra.css';
import '../css/download.css';
import '../css/footer.css';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './layouts/app.vue';

createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

I tried to copy the pages into the CMS and vice versa, but It just keep giving me errors.

I'm a beginner and I just don't get it using inertia, because in my SPA project, I'm using App.vue as a layout to call other pages like this :

```
    <NavbarVue/>
    <Home/>
    <Kenapa/>
    <Cerita/>
    <Karir/>
    <Lowongan/>
    <Media/>
    <Gabung/>
    <Mitra/>
    <Download/>
    <Footer/>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import NavbarVue from '../components/Navbar.vue';
    import Home from '../pages/Home.vue';
    import Media from '../pages/Media.vue';
    import Kenapa from '../pages/Kenapa.vue';
    import Cerita from '../pages/Cerita.vue';
    import Lowongan from '../pages/Lowongan.vue';
    import Karir from '../pages/Karir.vue';
    import Gabung from '../pages/Gabung.vue';
    import Mitra from '../pages/Mitra.vue';
    import Download from '../pages/Download.vue';
    import Footer from '../components/Footer.vue';
    
    </script>
```

But in Inertia I can't do that, Can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0):

## Migration

Make a new Laravel 9 project and follow the instructions for installing Breeze w/ Inertia nad Vue.

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia

You will then move the *.vue files over to the new project and parse them appropriately.

For instance, you may get data via Axios calls in your Spa. With Inertia, you pass data directly from the controllers.

Furthermore, you will have to import your controllers and all related PHP files into the new project and parse them to align with the Inertia design structure.

## Testing

If you haven't already, I highly suggest you get into testing with PHPUnit. Properly tested code can make migrating files from one repository to another less nerve-wracking.

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/testing

## Conclusion

Overall, this would be a massive project that could possibly take months. But if you intend to combine two completely different projects into one, that complexity will require it, especially if neither is tested.